# Graph API PHP SDK - How to get FB.streampublish style box

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a streampublish box with facebook's new graph api example. I am using this code but its not working. Any help guys!

```
<script>
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'stream.publish',
     message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
     attachment: {
       name: 'Connect',
       caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
       description: (
         'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
         'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
         'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
       ),
       href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js'
     },
     action_links: [
       { text: 'Code', href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js' }
     ],
     user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about Connect'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
</script>
```

Comment: What does not working mean? It explodes?

Comment: Means the streampublish box does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you intialized or called the Fb scripts properly....

It goes something like

> FB.init("API Key", "xd_receiver.htm");
>
>
>    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
>         FB.init({
>           appId   : 'getAppId(); ?>',
>           session : , // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
>           status  : true, // check login status
>           cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
>           xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
>         });
>         // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
>         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
>           window.location.reload();
>         });
>       };
>       (function() {
>         var e = document.createElement('script');
>         e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
>         e.async = true;
>         document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
>       }());

i dont actually remember the proper link to this in facebook

but i think u need to connect and call the FBJS properly to get this right!!!

may be this wou;d help!!!

Comment: I was missing the <div id=fb-root>